# ES6 Module Export - DOM Element Extended Method

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

When it comes to custom extended element methods such as PlainJS [closest()](https://plainjs.com/javascript/traversing/get-closest-element-by-selector-39/) DOM Element method:

```
// closest polyfill
this.Element && function(ElementPrototype) {
    ElementPrototype.closest = ElementPrototype.closest ||
    function(selector) {
        var el = this;
        while (el.matches && !el.matches(selector)) el = el.parentNode;
        return el.matches ? el : null;
    }
}(Element.prototype);
```

What would be the safest way to export and import an extension methods such as this with ES6 Module Imports/Exports? Placing export in front of the method definition leads to an "unexpected token this" error. What is the best approach to exporting to including IIFEs with the ES6 module system.

If the goal is to use a method such as `.closest()` as an Element class method, wrapping in another exportable function doesn't seem right.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: You don't need to export it, you just run it. `import 'path/to/your/lib.js';`

Comment: Would performing an import using that syntax cause every exported function within hypothetical `lib.js` file to be imported or simply the extended class methods? [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) indicates "for side effects only, without importing any bindings", but that doesn't really specify.

Comment: Nope, if you don't specify where to import - then nothing will be imported to the current scope.

Answer (score 0):

Your code won't work with module system - all modules are run in strict mode, therefore global this is undefined.

You have two options:

- export function taking `Element` as argument and extend that object. That's probably the best option - your module has single responsibility - extend it's argument. It doesn't bother with finding reference to global object, it will work everywhere.
- use empty export, empty import and extend global `Element`

In `polyfill.js`:

```
if (typeof Element === 'function') {
    Element.prototype.closest = ...
}
export {}; // empty export to signal to your module loader that's ES6 module
```

In main.js:

```
import 'polyfill.js'; // import for side-effects only
```